# Electomagnetic Field Quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electromagnetism

From Quantum Field Theory by Franz Mandl and Graham Shaw page 4.

When we are expanding the vector potential as a Fourier series;

$\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\vec{A}(\vec{x},t) = \sum\limits_{k}\sum\limits_{r}(\frac{\hbar c^2}{2V\omega_k})^{1/2}\vec{\varepsilon_r}(\vec{k})[a_r(\vec{k},t)e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}+a_r^*(\vec{k},t)e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}]$

I did not understand how we can determine the constant term $(\frac{\hbar c^2}{2V\omega_k})^{1/2}$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The point is that $\langle \mathbf{k}_1| \mathbf{k}_2 \rangle$ should be Lorentz invariant. This is ensured if: $$\langle \mathbf{k}_1| \mathbf{k}_2 \rangle \propto E_{\mathbf{p}}$$ I don't own the book you are referring to, but you should be able to verify the above equation by finding the commutation relations $[a(\mathbf{k}_1),a(\mathbf{k}_2)]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That factor is there because they quantize the field in a box and not in the continuum. When you take the continuum limit one gets 
$$
\int d^3k \rightarrow \sum_k \sqrt{\frac{\hbar c^2}{V}}
$$
by dimensional analysis.

The $1/\sqrt{2\omega_k}$ is related to Lorentz invariance.
A factor of $1/2\omega_k$ makes the measure $ d^3k/2\omega_k$ Lorentz invariant ([see this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83260/lorentz-invariant-integration-measure)) and the remaining $\sqrt{2\omega_k}$ goes with the creation operators so that the definite momentum states
$$
|k\rangle = \sqrt{2\omega_k} a^\dagger(k)|0\rangle
$$
have a Lorentz invariant measure too, as @Hunter explains.