# Where does this relativistic relation involving the delta function come from?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, notation, integration, dirac-delta-distributions

\begin{equation}
\int\delta(E^2-\mathbf{p}^2-m^2)dE=\frac{1}{2E_\mathbf{p}}
\end{equation}

Shouldn't integrating the delta function like this just give 1?

Comment: Have a look at e.g. [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167813/50583). And your integration variable shouldn't be $E$ - how should $E$ be able to occur on the RHS?

Comment: $\delta(f(x)) = \sum_k\frac1{|f'(x^*_k)|}\delta(x-x^*_k)$ where the $x^*_k$s are the zeroes of $f$...and you are probably integrating over positive energies alone...

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yeah I don't like it either hence why I'm asking if anyone can clarify what its trying to say

Comment: Its from some lecture notes, here is the context: http://imgur.com/HPg1GZT

Comment: The identity given by @Phoenix87 above can be found in Kusse & Westwig's _Mathematical Physics: Applied Mathematics for Scientists and Engineers_ (among other places, I'm sure, but that's where I know where to find it.)  It can also be proven by splitter the original integral up into small regions about each zero $x^*_k$, requiring that $f$ be invertible in each such small region, and then changing variables to integrate over $f$ instead of $x$ in each region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help from the comments this now makes sense.

\begin{equation}
\int \delta(E^2-p^2-m^2)dE
\end{equation}
With $$E_p^2-p^2-m^2=0$$
Use substitutions 
\begin{equation}
f(E)=E^2-p^2-m^2\quad df=2EdE
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int \delta(f)\frac{df}{2E(f)}=\frac{1}{2E_p}
\end{equation}
$E(f)$ is easily found by inverting $f$

Thanks!