# Lorentz covariant completeness relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, operators, momentum, lorentz-symmetry

Let be $$ P^\mu |p> = p^\mu |p> $$
i.e. $|p>$ is the eigen-vector of the 4-momentum operator.

Where does the following Lorentz-covariant completeness relation come from?

$$
\int d^4p \theta(p^0) \delta(p^2 + m^2)|p><p| = 1 .
$$

Comment: hint: act with both sides on $|p'\rangle$, and use $\langle p|p'\rangle\propto \delta(\boldsymbol p-\boldsymbol p')$, together with $\mathrm dp\ \Theta(p^0)\delta(p^2+m^2)\propto \mathrm d\boldsymbol p$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform thank you. I would like to know how to derive it from relativistic quantum mechanics. Can you give me some references?

Comment: Because I would like to understand better the theory than calculus... This completeness relation has to come from some Lorentz invariant principle or Lorentz transformation of states $|p>$...

Comment: I would like to understand also the minus sign to my question...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I searched here a question like this one, but I didn't find it. I tried to derive the relation, but the problem is that I understood that all of my efforts were wrong, so I don't see the importance of write them here...

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83260/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are required to prove this. First, you haven't really defined your state $|p\rangle$ in its entirety since you haven't defined what normalization you are using for this state. In the formula above, it seems to me that you are using the normalization
$$
\langle {\bf p} | {\bf p}' \rangle = \frac{2 E_p }{ 2\pi } \delta^3 ( {\bf p} - {\bf p'} )
$$
Then, the completeness relation is
$$
1 = \int  d^3 p   \frac{2\pi}{2 E_p } | {\bf p} \rangle \langle {\bf p} | 
$$
Finally, you have to show that (do this yourself)
$$
\int  d^3 p   \frac{1}{2 E_p } = \int \frac{d^4 p}{ 2\pi }  \theta ( p^0 ) \delta (p^2 + m^2 ) 
$$
which then implies
$$
1 = \int d^4 p  \theta ( p^0 ) \delta ( p^2 + m^2 )  | {\bf p} \rangle \langle {\bf p} | 
$$