# Lorentz invariance of measure $\int \frac{d^3 p}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

The scalar quantum field operator is defined

$$\phi_0(\vec x,t) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}} \left(a_p e^{-ipx}+a_p^{\dagger}e^{ipx}\right)$$

in Schwartz eq. 2.78. Here $\omega_p = \sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}$. One can show that

$$\int \frac{d^3\vec{k}}{2\omega_k} = \int d^4k \delta(k^2-m^2)\theta(k^0)$$

is a Lorentz invariant measure. I don't see how the measure in the definition of the quantum field is Lorentz invariant because of that square root.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83260/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I looked at the links and don't see an answer to my question.

Comment: Perhaps: The measure in the first integral above is is not necessarily Lorentz invariant, but the expression as a whole is because it is an operator that produces Lorentz invariant states when it acts upon kets. As in: 

$$\phi(\vec x) |0\rangle = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2\omega_p} e^{-ip\cdot x} |\vec{p}\rangle$$

where we used $a^{\dagger}_p|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega_p}} |\vec{p}\rangle$.

Comment: Along with 

$$\langle 0 |\phi(\vec x)|\vec{p}\rangle = e^{ip\cdot x}.$$

And since the $\phi$ operator produces Lorentz invariant things, it is Lorentz invariant.

Is this true? Can this be made rigorous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to construct the field such that
$$
\langle\vec{p}|\phi(x)|0\rangle=e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x}}
$$
and the definition is $\langle \vec{p}|=\langle 0|\sqrt{2\omega_p} a_p$, i.e. the state $|\vec{p}\rangle$ have an invariant inner product:
$$
\langle \vec{k}|\vec{p}\rangle=2\omega_p (2\pi)^3\delta^3(\vec{p}-\vec{k})
$$
such that the identity operator can be writen as:
$$
\mathcal{1}=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2\omega_p}|p\rangle\langle p|
$$
so the square root is just cancelling the square root of the $\langle \vec{p}|$ state.

All this is convention. The [Weinberg texbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521670535) chooses a different one in witch 
$$
\langle \vec{k}|\vec{p}\rangle= (2\pi)^3\delta^3(\vec{p}-\vec{k})
$$
and the price is to introduce a new factor into the Lorentz transformation of the state $|\vec{p}\rangle$:
$$
U(\Lambda)|\vec{p}\rangle = \sqrt\frac{(\Lambda p)^0}{p^0} |\vec{p}_{\Lambda}\rangle
$$

Comment: I think you may have misread my question. I am not asking about
$\int \frac{d^3k}{2\omega_k}.$
Rather I am asking why $$\int \frac{d^3k}{\sqrt{2\omega_k}}$$ is Lorentz invariant.

Comment: @Dwagg I edited, see if now this answers?

Comment: @Noguira In your last statement, are you talking about the first equation in my question?

Comment: @Dwagg This $\sqrt{2\omega_p}$ that appears in the field expresion (your first formula), is just there to cancel the square root of the definition of the state $\langle \vec{p}|$ in order to give what you want, the $e^{ipx}$

Comment: Okay. In particular, the first formula is *not* Lorentz invariant by itself? It is constructed to make $\langle 0 | \phi(x,t)|\vec{p}\rangle = e^{ipx}=$ Lorentz invariant?

Comment: @Dwagg The first line can be made Lorentz invariant by assigning the operators $a_{\vec p}$ and $a_{\vec p}^\dagger$ the corresponding transformation properties. Whether or not that's a beautiful convention is a different question.

Comment: @Dwagg, yes, after all, the field $\phi(x)$ is not Lorentz invariant, but transforms as $\phi(\Lambda x)$, it's a nontrivial representation (just the vacuum is a trivial representation).

Answer (score 3):

The measure you consider is **not** Lorentz invariant. The point is that, under Lorentz transformations, $a_p$ and $a_p^\dagger$ are not $p$-scalar fields but they  take a factor which compensates the failure of the measure to be Lorentz invariant, and the integral defining the quantum  field produces a scalar field. Nogueira's answer includes all information necessary to write down the transformation rule of $a_p$ and its Hermitian conjugate companion.
However all that is matter of convention, since one could use the invariant measure from scratch.