# A question about the Lorentz transformation of "infinitesimals"

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, inertial-frames, invariants

**Notations conventions:** $p$ stands for the momentum (so $d^3p$ is the differential element according to which we integrate, for the $3$ space coordinates). A Lorentz transformation is denoted by $\Lambda$. I denote $\vec p = (p^0,p^1,p^2,p^3)$ the 4-vector energy-momentum while I denote $p$ the spacial momentum.

I was reading a course about QFT, and inside an integral $\int u(\vec p)d^3p$, after the use of substitution $p \leftrightarrow \Lambda p$, they use this relation:

$$
\dfrac{d^3(\Lambda p)}{(\Lambda p)^0} = \dfrac{d^3p}{p^0}
$$

It seems to be pretty obvious for the author, so I might have missed something.

I know that $p^0 = \sqrt{m^2 + p^2}$ and $(\Lambda p)^0 = \sqrt{m^2 + (\Lambda p)^2}$ (where I use the notation convention for a 3-vector $p$, $p^2 = p\cdot p$)
How do you derive this relation?

Comment: Would you be able to clarify the terms in the equation?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83260/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measure $d^3p$ is unaffected by *rotations*, neither  is $p^0$.

For *boosts* can restrict to 1+1 dimensions as the transverse momentum components are not affected by a boost.

Now parameterise the mass-shell by the rapidity $s$, so that
$$
p^0=m\cosh s\\
p^1=m\sinh s
$$
then
$
dp^1= m\cosh s \,ds$ and
$$
\frac{dp^1}{p^0}=ds.
$$
Under a Lorentz boost with rapidity $s_1$ we have $s\to s + s_1$ and  $d(s+s_1)=ds$ as $s_1$ is a constant.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!