# How to know if a measure is Lorentz invariant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, momentum, integration, invariants

In a Pr. Badis Ydri's book, 'A Modern Course on QFT', the following integral is said to imply that $d^3p/2E_p$ is indeed a Lorentz invariant. How so ? Does it have to do anything with the notion of "test functions" ? (of which, I know nothing)

(I'm not sure that calling $d^3p/2E_p$ a measure is correct. If not, could someone correct my title, please ? Thank you.)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83260/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53534/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Indeed; thank you @Qmechanic.