# Lorentz invariant phase Volume

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, field-theory, dirac-delta-distributions

I am trying to derive Lorentz Invariant phase volume,

$$\int \frac{d^3p}{2E} = \int d^4p \delta(p^2-m_0^2) \Theta(p_0)$$

$$\int dp_0 \delta(p^2 -m_0^2) \Theta (p_0) = \int dp_0 \delta(p_0^2-E_p^2)\Theta(p_0) $$
$$=\int \frac{1}{2E}(\delta(p_0-E) + \delta(p_0+E) dp_0 \Theta(p_0)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2E}$$
$$hence \int \frac{d^3p}{2E} = \int d^4p\delta (p^2 -m_0^2)\Theta(p_0)$$

My only doubt is the $$\delta(p^2-m_0^2)$$ is not defined owing to Einstien relation$$(p^2=m^2)$$ so whether this integration is defined...

Please help me...

Comment: What do you mean by $\delta(p^2-m_0^2)$ "not being defined"?

Comment: due to mass-shell condtion p^2 = m^2 always fixed then what is meaning of integartion from +\infty to -\infty in momentum space

Comment: The integration is over all of 4-momentum space, not just over $p$s that fulfill $p^2 = m_0^2$. That's why the $\delta$ is there.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83260/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53534/2451 and links therein.

Comment: got it, so p^0 take value very close to E, and d^3p is all over space. Is it correct

Comment: Thank you so much Your answer helped I am new to QED. I was just wandering whether K_0 or p_0 as variable can have  value other than E_k (off-shell)