# Lorentz invariant phase space

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

This is regarding Lorentz invariant phase space volume,

I am doing in following way,

$$I=\int dk^0 \delta(k^2-m_0^2) \Theta(k_0) = \int dk^0  \delta(k_0^2-E_k^2) \Theta(k_0)$$
where $$E_k = \sqrt{\mathbf{k^2}+m_0^2}$$

From mass shell (Einstien relation) relation ..

$$k_0^2 = E_k$$ which means that $\delta$ function is singular, if it is for mass shell particle.
hence we can integrate around small uncertainty around $k_0$ , $\Delta k_0$,

which means that,
\begin{equation}
I = \int_{\Delta k_0} dk_0 \frac{1}{2k_0} (\delta(k_0 - E_k) + \delta(k_0+E_k))\Theta(k_0) = \frac{1}{2E_k}
\end{equation}
hence
$$\int\frac{d^3k}{2E} = \int d^3k \int_{\Delta k_0} dk_0 \delta(k^2-m_0^2)\Theta(k_0)$$
since $d^3k$ integration is all over three dimensional momentum space and $$k_0 = E_k = \sqrt{\mathbf{k}^2+m_0^2}$$ integration over small uncertainty of $k_0$ wiil also converted into all over k_0  space (or 4-momentum space)becaus of its dependence on $\mathbf{k}$ which runs over all three dimensional momentum space.

hence,
$$\int \frac{d^3k}{2E} = \int d^4k \delta(k^2-m_0^2)\Theta(k_0)$$. I found here un the help page that

integral I can also be written as(instead of putting the delta integration see eq 1)

$$I = dk_0 \delta(k_0 -E_k)\frac{1}{2k_0}\Theta(k_0)=\frac{1}{2E_k}$$
$$\int \frac{d^3k}{2E} = \int d^4k\delta(k_0^2-m_0^2)\Theta(k_0)$$

Please help me if my understanding is correct

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/690167/2451

Comment: Hi Vivek. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Ok I am really sorry for this, since i was not completely satisfied with the answer I asked it again,

Comment: General tip: When a question is edited, it automatically enters the review queue.